# Bootstrap, how to change order for cols when stacking the elements?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a footer which looks like this:

[image: this]

With this code:

```
<div class="row" style="font-size: 70%;padding-bottom:1%;margin-bottom:1%;">

    <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-2" style="color:grey">
      Copyright 2017 SoContact
    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-2" style="padding-right: 0px;margin-right: 0px;">
      <a href="mentions.php" style="color:grey">MENTIONS LEGALES</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-1" style="padding-left: 0px;margin-left: 0px;">
      <a href="cgv.php" style="color:grey">CGV</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-1" style="padding-left: 0px;margin-left: 0px;">
      <a href="faq.php" style="color:grey">FAQ</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-1" style="padding-left: 0px;margin-left: 0px;">
      <a style="color:grey">actualités</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2" style="padding-left: 0px;margin-left: 0px;">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> &nbsp;<a style="color:grey">CONTACTEZ-NOUS</a>
    </div>
    <br>

</div>
```

On smartphones the order of the footer items will be:

```
Copyright 2017 SoContact
MENTIONS LEGALES
CGV
FAQ
actualités
CONTACTEZ-NOUS
```

But I need to change the order when staking, like that:

```
FAQ
CONTACTEZ
ACTUALITES
MENTIONS LEGALES
CGV
Copyright 2017 SoContact
```

I have tried to play with `col-sm-push` and `pull` but I can"t find the proper combination ?

Any clue ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order of columns with [push and pull](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#push-and-pull).

With Bootstrap 4 this has become `push-viewport-unit / pull-viewport-unit`.

This is not my strongest point but I think in your case it would be:

```
<div class="row" style="font-size: 70%;padding-bottom:1%;margin-bottom:1%;">

    <div class="col-lg-2 push-lg-10" style="color:grey">
      Copyright 2017 SoContact
    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-2 push-lg-4" style="padding-right: 0px;margin-right: 0px;">
      <a href="mentions.php" style="color:grey">MENTIONS LEGALES</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-1 push-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;margin-left: 0px;">
      <a href="cgv.php" style="color:grey">CGV</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-1 pull-lg-4" style="padding-left: 0px;margin-left: 0px;">
      <a href="faq.php" style="color:grey">FAQ</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-1 pull-lg-2" style="padding-left: 0px;margin-left: 0px;">
      <a style="color:grey">actualités</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 pull-lg-5" style="padding-left: 0px;margin-left: 0px;">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> &nbsp;<a style="color:grey">CONTACTEZ-NOUS</a>
    </div>
    <br>

</div>
```